# Pi rebooting on 1 specific apt-get installation

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, apt, crash

I am experiencing a very peculiar problem with my Raspberry Pi 3 (model B V1.2), running the latest version of Raspbian (the June 2017 version).

Whenever I try to install `nginx` using `apt-get`, my Pi reboots (after one failure, this results in having to execute `dpkg --configure -a` which also causes the Pi to reboot). **I only have this problem using nginx; I can install apache (another webserver), do upgrades, install any other package except nginx.**

When I tried putting the `dpkg --reconfigure -a` command in my /etc/rc.local, the device effectively got stuck in a boot loop.

At first I thought the image/OS was corrupt, since this might occur, but the problem persists across fresh reinstalls.

After some searching I found it might be a problem with the power supply; it is connected to an outlet using my Samsung cellphone charger.

I have checked cpu/memory usage, and it's nowhere near noteworthy.

I fixed it by plugging the sd-card in my other Raspberry Pi **2**; that Pi seems to be capable of actually installing `nginx` to the sd-card which I can afterwards plug back in my original Raspberry Pi 3.